# c# pluggable factory / static initialization

Tags: c#, static

I am looking for a c# equivelent of my code for a pluggable factory.  The advantage of the linked method is that static initialization result in a push operation, where each plugin adds itself to the factory.

C++ code for a pluggable factory: (http://codepad.org/7pgzaaAK)

```
// base class for plugins
class Foo{
public:
    virtual std::string getName()const=0;
    virtual void exercise()const=0;
};

// plugin factory
class FooFactory{
    public:
    static Foo* GetA(std::string s);
    typedef std::map<std::string,Foo*(*)(void)> mapType;
    static mapType& getA();
};

FooFactory::mapType& FooFactory::getA(){static mapType getA;return getA;}
Foo* FooFactory::GetA(std::string s)
{return getA().find(s)!=getA().end()?getA()[s]():0;} // to simplify access

// helper function to add the fun
template<typename T>
Foo* getNew(){  return new T; }

// use the CRTP to automatically register the object with the factory.
template <typename T> struct Reg { Reg() { /*cout << "registering a " << T().getName( <<endl;*/
FooFactory::getA().insert(std::pair<std::string, Foo*(*)()>(T().getName(), &getNew<T>));} };

template <typename T>
class Foo_reg:public Foo{
public:
    Foo_reg(){&reg;}; // using a reff to the static is enough to force initialization of the static earlier
    static Reg<T> reg;
};
template <typename T> Reg<T> Foo_reg<T>::reg;

/////////////////
class FooBar:public Foo_reg<FooBar>{ // automatic registration with the factory
public:
    FooBar(){a=10;}
    virtual std::string getName()const{return "Foo Bar";}
    virtual void exercise()const {cout <<a;}
private:
    int a;
};

// exercise the factory and objects.
int main(){
    Foo* foo=FooFactory::GetA("Foo Bar");
    foo->exercise();
}
```

In C# i can see 2 ways of doing this, both of them pull operations

1. Have an explicit pre-built list of all plugins, which has to be maintained seperatly from the plugins themselves.
2. Use code reflection to iterate through all types, checking if they are castable to Foo and initialize their statics, on any dll load and program start.

Is it possible to do this without having to resort to these methods?

Comment: as an aside, should i include the codepad code here, or there?

Comment: generally, yes, it doesn't hurt to include code snippets in questions. SO has formatting tags for code so that it renders nicely

Comment: thanks for the feedback - code snippet edited in.

Comment: what did you go for in the end? 

I find myself very tempted to use "Activator.CreateInstance" inside my plugably factory

Comment: added my resolution to the issue below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldnt worry about reflection to much. Even PEX has no trouble using it. Simply put, by reflection, you're just checking the metadata of an assembly and see if it defined any classes that implement a certain interface or are marked with a certain attribute, this is very fast! Anyways, the CLR will never run code that is not being called explicitly so no, you have to resort to some kind of pulling mechanism (even if you make it look like a push mechanism)

Answer (score 0):

realizing that the only real requiremnt here was that at the end of the day we have a lookup between a type identifier (string/Type) and a function which allows us to get an instance of that type i ended up resolving this with the following pattern:

```
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<TConstructor, Node>> Types =
        new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<TConstructor, Node>>();
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, string> classNameMap = new Dictionary<Type, string>();

    private class constructableNode<T> where T : Node, new()
    {
        public constructableNode()
        {
            var t = new T();
            Types[t.Type()] = new KeyValuePair<TConstructor, Node>(thisTConstructor, t);
            classNameMap[typeof (T)] = t.Type();
        }

        private static T thisTConstructor()
        {
            var t = new T();
            return t;
        }
    }

    public static Node GetA(string s)
    {
        if (Types.ContainsKey(s) == false)
        {
            UpdateAvailableTypes();
        }
        if (Types.ContainsKey(s) == false)
        {
            throw new BadNodeType(s);
        }
        // look up the correct constructor, and call it.
        return Types[s].Key();
    }

    public static void UpdateAvailableTypes()
    {
        Assembly targetAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); // or whichever - could iterate dlls in the plugins folder or something
        UpdateAvailableTypes(targetAssembly);
        classNameMap[typeof (Node)] = "BaseNode"; // HARD CODED INTO the node type itself also
    }

    private static void UpdateAvailableTypes(Assembly targetAssembly)
    {
        IEnumerable<Type> subtypes = targetAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof (Node)));
        Type nodeConstructor = typeof (constructableNode<>);
        foreach (Type currentType in subtypes)
        {
            // this line throwing an error means that the Node type does not have an empty constructor.
            Activator.CreateInstance(nodeConstructor.MakeGenericType(currentType));

        }
    }
```

This is a simple method, but the cost of the dynamic Invoke each call is a bit steep compared to other options, and when i first used this pattern for the section below, it was 80% of the critical code path runtime.

HOWEVEVER: Due to performance constraints a different pattern of construction was needed for part of my code which was rebuilt quickly (potentially millions of objects, wanted sub-second response time). (see discussion at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haibo_luo/archive/2005/11/17/494009.aspx for various methods of reflection based construction)

for these i needed the following construction paradigm, whereby the intermediate lookup through the function call to the generic class was washed out

```
static buildCostItems()
        {
            //from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haibo_luo/archive/2005/11/17/494009.aspx
            AssemblyBuilder asmBldr = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("inmemory"),
                                                                                    AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            ModuleBuilder modBldr = asmBldr.DefineDynamicModule("helper");
            TypeBuilder typeBldr = modBldr.DefineType("ClassFactory");
            Type tci = typeof (CostsItem);
            IEnumerable<Type> types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(tci.IsAssignableFrom);
 //// Note -- assumption of currently executing assembly -- this isn't a requirement, but didn't need the dynamic callback capabilities of the Node constructor here.
            List<Type> enumerable = types as List<Type> ?? types.ToList();
            foreach (Type type in enumerable)
            {
                MethodBuilder methBldr = typeBldr.DefineMethod(type.Name,
                                                               MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, type,
                                                               new[] {typeof (CostsItem)});
                ILGenerator ilgen = methBldr.GetILGenerator();
                ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
                ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, type.GetConstructor(new[] {typeof (CostsItem)}));
                ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            }
            Type baked = typeBldr.CreateType();
            foreach (Type type in enumerable)
                ctors.Add(type,
                          (CtorCloneDelegate)
                          Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (CtorCloneDelegate), baked.GetMethod(type.Name)));
        }
```